# Dax Divide function not showing alternate result

Tags: dax, powerpivot

Below Dax function is not showing alternate results for 0 in both column 1 and column 2.

=divide(sum('Database'[Column 1]),sum('Database'[column 2]),"-")

Regards,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the DAX DIVIDE function. If the alternate result is not showing up then your denominator is not exactly equal to zero. It could be something like 0.0000001 for example.